# How do you use DTOs in Play Framework scala templates?

Tags: java, templates, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm playing around with a Play application and I want to pass a list of DTOs from the controller to the template:`@(dtos: List[MyDTO])`

My first instinct is to add the DTO class to a new package named `dtos`, but if I do that I get an error when running the app: `not found: type MyDTO`. I tried adding `@import dtos.MyDTO` in the template, but I still get the error. If i put the DTO in the `model` package it works just fine, but I don't want to do that as I don't want that to interfere with Ebean table generation and evolutions.

So what packages are seen by default in the template, and how can I make my class visible to the template from a new package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your Build.scala:

```
PlayProject(...) settings(
  ...
  templatesImport ++= Seq(
    "com.company.dto", "com.company.useful", ...
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware about that setting. I did <code>templatesImport += "dtos._"</code> and it works now.